# finding the syntax error in my function in bash

Tags: bash, syntax, compiler-errors

Here is the function.

```
function a {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    done < "path{path_in}"

#working code above. If I put '}' here the code runs and works.
    echo
    echo "--Letter Count--"
    for letter in "${LETTERS[@]}" do
        letter_upper=`toupper $letter`
        upper_int= `atoi $letter_upper`
        lower_int= `atoi $letter`
        upper_count= ${myArray[${upper_int}]}
        lower_count= ${myArray[${lower_int}]}
        echo "$letter_upper $(($upper_count + $lower_count))"
    done

} #line 102


#error: line 102: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

This is the broken part of the function for some reason. If I put the '}' at any line after

> done < "path(path_in)"

then the running the code will give me that syntax error.

Comment: The number of `{` and `}` differs.

Comment: Run your script through https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Need a `;` before the do ... i.e. `for letter in "${LETTERS[@]}" ; do`

Answer (score 0):

best way to know if you have too many or too less `{` `}` is to count them and after counting you had 7 in your `function a` so you would receive an error for this.

I don't think you need to use `{` `}` in your function, just when you declare it, i have an article which should help you with Bash variables and command substitution at the following webpage,
http://www.compciv.org/topics/bash/variables-and-substitution/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues but the predominant one is that you put spaces after the `=` signs. You need to remove those spaces; e.g. `` upper_int=`atoi $letter_upper` ``  instead of `` upper_int= `atoi $letter_upper` `` .

But, perhaps more importantly, you need to run ShellCheck on your code and heeds its warnings.

Of course this doesn’t explain the error you’re observing. Based only on the fragment you’ve posted we can’t help you fix that.